# Why does my custom Swing label take so long to initialize?

Tags: java, performance, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

I've made a custom subclass of `JLabel`.  I have a single instance of this, inside a single `JPanel`, inside a single `JFrame`.  I do *not* override the `paintComponent()` method; all the class does is change the background color when the cursor hovers over it.

The `JFrame` loads immediately, but for several seconds the `JPanel` is left undrawn.  I verified that this is because of my custom class by overriding `paintComponent()` and adding some debug `println()` statements.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics context)
{
    System.out.println("Painting...");
    super.paintComponent(context);
    System.out.println("Painted.");
}
```

The strange thing is, it's drawn instantly when I use `Panel` instead of `JPanel` or `Label` instead of `JLabel`.

Where is this lag coming from?

EDIT: Some example code.  Nothing is actually drawn; look at the console message delay.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JLabel implements MouseListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

    public Example()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("Constructed.");
    }

    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("Painting component...");
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Painted.");
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) { }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) { }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) { }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) { }

    public static void main(final String[] arguments)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(new Example());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Set visible.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Without your posting a compilable runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), your guess is better than ours. But if you really need our help and not our SWAGs, consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). You won't regret the effort, and neither will we.

Comment: Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manuipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My code doesn't lag:

My SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LabelTest extends JPanel {
   public LabelTest() {
      add(new MyLabel("Fubar!"));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      LabelTest mainPanel = new LabelTest();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("LabelTest");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyLabel extends JLabel {
   private static final Color BACKGROUND_DEFAULT = new Color(200, 200, 255);
   private static final Color BACKGROUND_MOUSEOVER = new Color(255, 200, 200);
   private static final int PREF_W = 200;
   private static final int PREF_H = 100;

   public MyLabel(String text) {
      super(text, SwingConstants.CENTER);
      setOpaque(true);
      setBackground(BACKGROUND_DEFAULT);
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         @Override
         public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            setBackground(BACKGROUND_MOUSEOVER);
         }

         @Override
         public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            setBackground(BACKGROUND_DEFAULT);
         }

      });
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      int width = Math.max(super.getPreferredSize().width, PREF_W);
      int height = Math.max(super.getPreferredSize().height, PREF_H);
      return new Dimension(width, height);
   }
}
```

This suggests to me that the problem isn't in the concept of a JLabel whose background changes via a MouseListener, but rather you've got a bug somewhere in your code. Where? Who knows until you post compilable runnable code, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), like the one I've posted above.

Comment: -1, because it's a pretty unhelpful answer.  It acts as a reminder to use SSCCEs, but you posted this literally fifteen minutes after your comment, while I was in the middle of putting my SSCCE together.

Comment: @Andrew Mine?  Yes.  (That is, it demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: @Maxpm  Why would I be asking about your code, in a comment on HFoE's answer that starts with *"My code doesn't lag:"*?  Note that I, and possibly others, are waiting to hear your answer before bothering to try either code.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, Hovercraft's code compiles and runs without lag.

Comment: So, if HFoE's code works, it is an answer to the question and it then seems you are merely upset about being prompted to post an SSCCE when HFoE was willing to try and solve the problem without one.  Just because posting an SSCCE is a good idea, does not mean the person who requests it is unwilling to work on the problem short of that.  Personally I think you should get over your irritation (take a walk perhaps) then mark the answer correct.

Comment: @Maxpm: I'm not sure how this deserves a down-vote. It isn't insulting to you or wrong per se, but does demonstrate that the concept itself is not the cause of the problem -- something that can't be done in the comment. I can see your posting a critical comment perhaps, but again not a down-vote. But that's your decision or course.

Comment: @Andrew I don't appreciate the condescending attitude, first of all.  Second, I asked why my code didn't work, not for someone to give me a freebie to copy and paste.